# Is there a way to read a key value pair separated by tabs?

Tags: shell, awk, sed, configuration, grep

I'm writing a building environment based on configuration files but got stuck parsing them. The environment contains Makefiles (bmake) which try to read the configurations for setting up `CFLAGS` accordingly.

The configuration file is kept simple, no special `=` sign required:

```
ident               Appname           # E.g. core.S:15: .ident $ident$
cpu                 arch (amd64, x86) # -march=cpuarch -mtune=cpuarch

option              debug             # Enable debugging.
option              sanitize          # Sanitize undefined behaviour.
option              asyncio           # Asynchronous I/O.
option              ccpipe            # GCC/Clang -pipe option.
```

I can't figure out the right regex for parsing these options with `grep`, `sed`, or `awk`. Because I would love to determine these features in simple `conditional statements` by `bmake`, e.g.

```
DBG_ENABLED!= $read if option debug is set$ ? yes : no.
.if ${DBG_ENABLED} != ""} || ${DBG_ENABLED} == "yes" || ${DBG_ENABLED} != "no"
CFLAGS+=      -O -g
.else
CFLAGS+=      -O2
.endif

PIPE_ENABLED!= $read if option ccpipe is set$ ? yes : no.
.if ${PIPE_ENABLED} != "no"
CFLAGS+=      -pipe
.endif
```

So how can I determine via shell commands that option `X` e.g. `option debug`, is set? I thought about grepping the file or using `awk`...

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear to me. Could you take your time and [edit] your question explaining a bit more in detail what you would like to achieve? At the moment I do not understand it. Also, you mention Makefiles, but the tags do not indicate this

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Sure I will see what I can do to make it more accurate.

Comment: Are you trying to generate a Makefile based on contents of a config file or read a config file within a hand-written Makefile?

Comment: I am trying to read a config file within a hand-written Makefile!

Comment: Did you want to include a column for state of the option, i.e. `0` or `1`, on, off, etc.? OR is just the mention of the option in the config file meant to indicate that it is "on"? Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the config file into an associative array:

```
$ declare -A opts="( $(awk -F'\t+' 'NF{print "["$1","$2"]=1"}' file) )"

$ for idx in "${!opts[@]}"; do echo "$idx=${opts[$idx]}"; done
cpu,arch (amd64, x86)=1
option,debug=1
option,asyncio=1
option,ccpipe=1
option,sanitize=1
ident,Appname=1
```

then just test `${opts["option,debug"]}` for being populated or not.

Or if you prefer to just get the options:

```
$ declare -A opts="( $(awk -F'\t+' '$1=="option"{print "["$2"]=1"}' file) )"

$ for idx in "${!opts[@]}"; do echo "$idx=${opts[$idx]}"; done
ccpipe=1
sanitize=1
asyncio=1
debug=1
```

Whichever syntax you prefer:

```
$ if (( ${opts[debug]} )); then echo "do debug stuff"; else echo "nope, dont do it"; fi
do debug stuff

$ if (( ${opts[fluff]} )); then echo "do debug stuff"; else echo "nope, dont do it"; fi
nope, dont do it

$ if [[ -n ${opts[debug]} ]]; then echo "do debug stuff"; else echo "nope, dont do it"; fi
do debug stuff

$ if [[ -n ${opts[fluff]} ]]; then echo "do debug stuff"; else echo "nope, dont do it"; fi
nope, dont do it
```

---

Update: since your file apparently isn't really tab-separated as you had stated it was, strip the comments then strip all remaining leading/trailing blanks and use the first remaining chain of white space as separators between the first field and the rest of the line (necessary to treat `arch (amd64, x86)` as a "field" in the first script):

```
$ declare -A opts="( $(awk '{sub(/#.*/,""); gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"")} NF{k=$1; sub(/[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+/,""); print "["k","$0"]=1"}' file) )"

$ for idx in "${!opts[@]}"; do echo "$idx=${opts[$idx]}"; done
cpu,arch (amd64, x86)=1
option,debug=1
option,asyncio=1
option,ccpipe=1
option,sanitize=1
ident,Appname=1

$ declare -A opts="( $(awk '{sub(/#.*/,""); gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"")} $1=="option"{print "["$2"]=1"}' file) )"

$ for idx in "${!opts[@]}"; do echo "$idx=${opts[$idx]}"; done
ccpipe=1
sanitize=1
asyncio=1
debug=1
```

---

Final update: all things considered this is probably what you really want:

```
$ declare -A opts="( $(awk '
{
    sub(/#.*/,"")
    gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"")
}

NF && ($1 != "ident") {
    f1 = $1
    sub(/[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+/,"")
    f2 = $0
    if (f1 == "option") {
        idx = f2
        val = 1
    } else {
        idx = f1
        val = f2
    }
    print "[" idx "]=\"" val "\""
}
' file ) )"

$ for idx in "${!opts[@]}"; do echo "$idx=${opts[$idx]}"; done
ccpipe=1
sanitize=1
asyncio=1
debug=1
cpu=arch (amd64, x86)
```